# Best way to log errors in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, logging

What's the best way to catch and log errors when developing a WCF service layer, and why?

I can think of three ways,

1) Manual try/catches around each method.

2) Leave the responsibility to the WCF engine.

3) Use a third party library such as Enterprise Library Policy Injection/Logging.

Comment: Refer to the following link for setting up log4net with WCF. In each webmethod you can add request and response information to the log file. [http://paulthecyclist.com/tag/log4net/](http://paulthecyclist.com/tag/log4net/)

Comment: Thanks for the link Shazia. The actual link should be: http://paulthecyclist.com/2012/04/06/catch-all-wcf-errors/ though.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would implement custom [IErrorHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) and use log4net

```
[AttributeUsage (AttributeTargets.Interface)]
public class ErrorPolicyBehaviorAttribute : Attribute, IContractBehavior, IErrorHandler
    {
    private ILog m_logger;

    #region IErrorHandler

    public void ProvideFault (Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
        {
        return;
        }

    public bool HandleError (Exception error)
        {
        m_logger.Error (error.Message, error);
        return true;
        }

    #endregion

    #region IContractBehavior

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior (ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
        {
        ...init logger
        ......Add this class to a list of dispatchRuntime.ChannelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers...
        }

    #endregion
    }
```

This class also implements IContractBehavior, so you can use it as Attribute on your service contracts.

```
[ErrorPolicyBehavior]
public interface IYourServiceContract
{ }
```

log4net is quite flexible, so you can log what you need and when you need.

Comment: I prefer using the .NET tracing - it's already built into the .NET framework, and is one less dependency on an external component.

Comment: @marc_s. Since .NET 1.1 i got used to log4net, since it offered much more flexibility than standard .NET tracing. One small and open-source (it means you can fix bugs there if you find any) lib dependency is not a big deal.

Comment: @fspirit, could you please provide the full code of your demo. I implemented the same code and introduced DividedByZero exception in one of my contract method. However breakpoint never hits Handle Error method.

Comment: @marc_s I don't know about `IErrorHandler` but WCF doesn't always log errors to a properly configured trace. A response serialization error once end up in a event log with a nice tag "A message was not logged."

Answer (score 10):

WCF can be configured to output traces for process milestones across all components of the applications, such as operation calls, code exceptions, warnings and other significant processing events.

The following is an `app.config` example to enable tracing.

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning" propagateActivity="true" >
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>

      <source name="myUserTraceSource" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>

    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml" 
           type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
           initializeData="TraceLog.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>

  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

You can read more about WCF Tracing from [**MSDN: Configuring Tracing**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx).

Microsoft provides a [**Service Trace Viewer Tool**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx) to read .svclog files.

Apart from tracing, you may also want to consider using [log4net](http://log4net.sourceforge.net/) for in-application logging.

Comment: if you already set up .NET tracing, why not use that functionality for application logging, too?? Removes another of those pesky dependencies on external components, and it works quite well indeed

Comment: @marc_s: Thank you for the suggestion. However, would you still use .NET tracing for logging events other than errors: like 'access hits'? ... and would you apply the same reasoning for the live environment?

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth your while to check out [log4net](http://log4net.sourceforge.net/). There is a good tutorial here on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/trace/log4net_intro.aspx).

Comment: I prefer using the .NET tracing - it's already built into the .NET framework, and is one less dependency on an external component

Comment: I also liked this log4net tutorial. Very comprehensive.  http://www.beefycode.com/category/log4net.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking for logging framework [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) is also a good option to consider. If you dont like to litter your code with try/catch around each method, you can try using [AOP frameworks](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AOP_Frameworks_Rating.aspx)  which would give you the ability to handle exceptions by marking the method with Attributes

Comment: We've had success using AoP via the Unity Interface Interceptor. Bit of a learning curve, especially around exception handling, but we now have a great reusable code block that logs all of our WCF I/O at info level (via log4net)

Answer (score 1):

I would go with number 1.  Mainly because of reduced overhead over number 3 and number 2 should just be a no-no.

Granted you still want to log to something say like a file or event manager.  But I personnally would use log4net for it since it's a bit lighter than all the entlib stuff.

Comment: number 1 is only really an option if you are expecting some other code throwing and exception and you want to handle it for the user in some way. Unhandled exceptions are always a possibility in .NET. Consider when the exception is raised by the service before the method itself has got a chance to call. Putting a 

try{...}catch(Exception e){LogException(e)}

seems like you are littering you code with logic that could best be handled in one central location.

Comment: I tend to agree try catch log is a pretty bloated way to solve the problem especially when an Error Behavior would solve this. Audience may also want to look at AOP, a style to prevent this repetitive style of coding - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming. Behaviors are a way to introduce these concepts when using WCF